# Adding NumberPicker value to database

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, numberpicker

Update, I got this working finally by calling an onValueChangedListener.

```
     layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText inputNotes = new EditText(MainActivity.this);

    final NumberPicker inputCount = new NumberPicker(MainActivity.this);
    inputCount.setMaxValue(50);
    inputCount.setMinValue(0);
    inputCount.clearFocus();
    inputCount.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
            OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int
                oldVal, int newVal) {

            }
        });
```

And calling that value when I post to the Parse.com database. Thank you.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Create a post.
        AnywallPost post = new AnywallPost();
        // Set the location to the current user's location
        post.setLocation(myPoint);
        post.setText(input.getText().toString());
        post.setNotes(inputNotes.getText().toString());

        final int valueCount = inputCount.getValue(); //getting valueCount from above
        post.setNumber(valueCount);
```

End update.

I want to add the value from my NumberPicker to the backend Parse.com database I have set up for my app. I've added the NumberPicker to the Post form. When I look at the table after saving a Post, I don't see a number but a nonsense text entry. Does anyone have suggestions on what I need to add to my code? Thanks.

The NumberPicker code in MainActivity:

```
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    final EditText inputNotes = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
    final NumberPicker inputCount = new NumberPicker(MainActivity.this);
    inputCount.setMinValue(0);
    inputCount.setMaxValue(50);
```

I'm saving the input with code further down in MainActivity.

```
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Create a post.
        AnywallPost post = new AnywallPost();
        // Set the location to the current user's location
        post.setLocation(myPoint);
        post.setText(input.getText().toString());
        post.setNotes(inputNotes.getText().toString());

        post.setNumber(inputCount.getContext().toString()); //This is where value for NumberPicker is saved. I need to change this line, I think.
```

The Post form with the NumberPicker:

[image]

I haven't gotten the Parse.com table to populate with the NumberPicker value. It writes something like com.parse.anywall.MainActivity... to that field.

[image]

Comment: How are you getting the value of the Picker? It doesn't seem like you are reading it at all.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosJ. I have gotten the value now, like I mention below. It is same result in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called `setOnValueChangedListener` for my NumberPicker and used that value to add to my database. I put code in update to the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried saving :

```
  Integer.toString(inputTime.getValue());
```

Comment: Why would you save it as a `String`?

Comment: the field bicyclistNumber is String

Comment: I guess I should be asking the OP that question. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, @Elenasys. I have added `Integer.toString(inputCount.getValue());` but it is same result in table. I changed my question to make it more logical.